# Find the font from a single ’C’ character

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-design, typefaces

I'm looking for the typeface from which this C came from. What The Font did not help.

[image]

Comment: The fewer glyphs you have, the harder it is to identify a font. You will probably have to scroll though lists of serif fonts to find something similar. Search terms such as: serif, Roman, might help narrow your search.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be [Georgia Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/products/bold-georgia-432492).

Comment: Close, but the soft teardrop on this ‘C’ isn’t present on Georgia Bold. This is from a logo designed in 1979, so it’s easier a unique ‘C’ or something obvious that’s right under my nose.

Comment: @RussellEtchen, sure, it may be an old logo, but it's a very sharp digital image so likely it's been vectorized-so either it was vectorized from the original font which could have changed it or it could have been remade using a font. This could be lots of things, sorry. Georgia Bold is close enough to right for me.